# Failed assertion: line 173 pos 12: 'renderObject.child == child': is not true

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, nestedscrollview

fix: Resolve failed assertion error when updating profile data
When updating profile data in the ProfileScreen widget, a failed assertion error was occurring, with the message "renderObject.child == child is not true". After investigating the issue, it was determined that the error was related to a mismatch between the expected and actual data types, which was causing an issue with rendering the updated profile data in the UI.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:inbox/core/utils/app_strings.dart';
import '../../../../../core/utils/app_colors.dart';
import '../../../controllers/auth/auth_cubit.dart';
import '../../../controllers/auth/auth_states.dart';
import '../widgets/my_profile_header.dart';
import '../widgets/profile_appbar.dart';

List<Tab> tabs = const [
  Tab(text: AppStrings.posts),
  Tab(text: AppStrings.videos),
];

class ProfileScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool fromSearch;

  const ProfileScreen({Key? key, required this.fromSearch}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<AuthCubit, AuthStates>(
      builder: (context, state) {
        var user = AuthCubit
            .get(context)
            .userEntity;

        if (state is UpdateProfilePicSuccessState) {
          AuthCubit.get(context).getCurrentUser();
        } else if (state is GetCurrentUserSuccessState) {
          user = AuthCubit
              .get(context)
              .userEntity;
        }


        return Scaffold(
          appBar: ProfileAppBar(user: user!, fromSearch: fromSearch),
          body: DefaultTabController(
            length: 2,
            child: NestedScrollView(
              headerSliverBuilder: (context, innerBoxIsScrolled) {
                return [
                  SliverPersistentHeader(
                    pinned: false,
                    delegate: MyProfileHeader(user: user!),
                  ),
                ];
              },
              body: Column(
                children: [
                  Align(
                    alignment: AlignmentDirectional.centerStart,
                    child: TabBar(
                      unselectedLabelColor: AppColors.gray,
                      labelColor: AppColors.black,
                      isScrollable: true,
                      labelStyle: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                      indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,
                      tabs: tabs,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: TabBarView(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          color: Colors.redAccent,
                        ),
                        Container(
                          color: Colors.blue,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

[rendered error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6MBO2.jpg)

Comment: Please add more details regarding the issue that you are describing.